# Wpf: Resize control in subgrid (row, column) to parent grid size

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

Weird question :)

I have a grid inside a tab control. Let's call it MainGrid. This MainGrid is divided in four via Rows/Comumns. So, i have four subgrids. Let's call them SubGrid00, SubGrid01, etc...

Inside each subgrid there is a control with the horizontal and vertical aligment configured as stretch.

What i want to achieve is to zoom to the size of the MainGrid any of the controls inside the subgrids with a double click.

I tried with:

```
SubGrid00.Children.Remove(Control00);
MainGrid.Children.Add(Control00);
```

... But it's not working...

Any Idea?
Thanks!

Comment: In case you don't need to animate this, you could simply set the `Grid.ColumnSpan` and `Grid.RowSpan` of the sub grid to `2`. In order to bring each sub grid to front, you would have to set its `Panel.ZIndex` property.

Comment: Great! Very smart solution. Now i had to fight with the visivility of the others subgrids (overlaping) and  put that subgrid in the index 0,0. This is just what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in the comment by [Clemens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1136211/clemens) works like a charm!

> In case you don't need to animate this, you could simply set the Grid.ColumnSpan and Grid.RowSpan of the sub grid to 2. In order to bring each sub grid to front, you would have to set its Panel.ZIndex property.